# How to remove recognizer from UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have UIButton and UIView, which I load on button (like setImage)
How can I remove recognizer from UIView so I could press the UIButton, not UIView?

Comment: `[self.view removeGestureRecognizer:yourRecognizer];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in [self.view gestureRecognizers])){
           if([gesture isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]){
             if (gesture.numberOfTapsRequired == 1) 
                [imageView removeGestureRecognizer:gesture];
           }
        }
```

You can remove all single Tap Gestures in your view using this